# node.js EventEmitter causes scope problems

Tags: node.js, event-handling, this

When using nodejs event system, I met with an annoying problem. As the code below shows, when a listener catch a event, the event emitter object owns 'this' in the callback function instead of the listener.

It's not a big problem if you put the callback in the listener's constructor, because besides pointer 'this', you can still use other variables defined in the constructor's scope, like the 'self' or 'that' way.

But, if the callback is put outside the constructor like the prototype methods, it appears to me that there is no ways to get the listener's 'this'.

Not very sure if there are any other solutions. And also, a little confused about why nodejs event emit use the emitter as the caller install of the listener?

```
util = require('util');
EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;

var listener = function () {
    var pub = new publisher();
    var self = this;
    pub.on('ok', function () {
        console.log('by listener constructor this: ', this instanceof listener);
        // output: by listener constructor this:  false

        console.log('by listener constructor self: ', self instanceof listener);
        // output: by listener constructor this:  true
    })
    pub.on('ok', this.outside);
}

listener.prototype.outside = function () {
    console.log('by prototype listener this: ', this instanceof listener);
    // output: by prototype listener this:  false
    // how to access to listener's this here?
}

var publisher = function () {
    var self = this;

    process.nextTick(function () {
        self.emit('ok');
    })
}

util.inherits(publisher, EventEmitter);

var l = new listener();
```

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/scoped-event-emitter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try binding the listener explicitly to the callback:

```
pub.on('ok', this.outside.bind(this));
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. But as project used a lot of event chains, it's still annoying to add this after every 'on' phrases. Any other solutions?

Comment: You can store the reference returned by `this.outside.bind(this)`, and use that when necessary...

Comment: How does this behave according to performance? The bind usually internally wraps the function in a self executing function for scoping. Wouldn't it be great - performance-wise - to add a possibility to pass a scope around? Because like this, the scoping function is created on every 'ok' event, isn't it?

Comment: @ThomasFankhauser no, the new (bound) function is created just once and reused for each event.